# C++ How can I mock an asio::awaitable method

Tags: c++, mocking, boost-asio, cppcoro

I want to mock the following line from boost asio library.

`auto bytes = co_await socket.async_read(boost::asio::buffer(data), boost::asio::use_awaitable);`

I thought of creating an interface which will represent the socket, then implement that interface for production by using asio and for testing by implementing a mock class of my own.

```
class MockSocket{
  asio::awaitable<size_t> async_read(boost::asio::buffer&& buffer){
    this.buffer = buffer;
    co_await this.something;
    co_return this.size;
  }

  void complete_read(string dataToPutInBuffer){
     this.buffer.write(dataToPutInBuffer);
     this.size = dataToPutInBuffer.length();
     this.something.resume();
  }
}
```

I have no idea what this.something should be. the asio::awaitable doesn't seem to have a resume() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async_result` or `async_initiate` to implement your own initiation function that takes an Asio [CompletionToken](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html).

Note also that Beast contains a stream that models [`AsyncStream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) - which is enough to satisfy e.g. `asio::async_read*` family of operations.

See it here: [test::stream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__test__stream.html)